# How to set ontouchlistner and swipe two candy on my multi imageview

Tags: android-studio, imageview, swipe, ontouchlistener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqwXO.png)
i am making candycrush type game for demo.I want to swipe to images

i am stuck with problem of using the method ontouchlistner and also want to swipe to images as like in candycrush game.

`private void reset() {
        for (int i = 0; i<r;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <c; j++)
            {
                Random rn = new Random();
                int answer = rn.nextInt(5) + 1;
                cell[i][j].setImageResource(candy[answer]);
                cell[i][j].isClickable();
                cell[i][j].setOnTouchListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        boolean b;
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            b =true;
            Toast.makeText(this, "touched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("path>>>",b+"");
            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS){
            Toast.makeText(this, "pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            b=false;
            Log.d("path>>>", b + "");
            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER){
            Toast.makeText(this, "hovered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            b=false;
            Log.d("path>>>", b + "");
            // Do what you want
            return true;
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE){
            Toast.makeText(this, "button release", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            b=true;
            Log.d("path>>>", b + "");
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: You need onTouch for the parent view. MotionEvent gives you the x,y coordinates touched in the parent view. From that you can figure which cells were touched.

Comment: So,Exactly what i need implement?